# Is there any way to retrieve a user's chat history in hangouts?

Tags: api, gmail, chat, history, google-hangouts

As developers, we can get a user's mails from Gmail (provided the authorization).  Is it possible to get hangouts chat history? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether chat history is enabled for the account. For Google Apps accounts, chat history can be enabled or disabled from the Admin console. If it is a regular Gmail account, then the it should be saved as any other email is. It will not end up in your inbox but if a user was chatting with "John" for example, you can search chat history by searching for mail from "John". Then emails and chat history are displayed.